# Trigger on status change

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to write a trigger in SQL, first of all I show you my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE ZAMOW
(
    IDZAMOW int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
    IDKLIENTA int not null REFERENCES KLIENT(IDKLIENTA),
    DATA DATE not null DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    STATUS char(1) CHECK(STATUS = 'P' OR STATUS = 'W' OR STATUS = 'Z' OR STATUS = 'A' )DEFAULT('P')
)

CREATE TABLE ZAMOCZESCI
(
    IDZAMOW int not null REFERENCES ZAMOW(IDZAMOW),
    IDCZESCI int not null REFERENCES CZESC(IDCZESCI),
    ILOSC float not null
)

CREATE TABLE CZESC
(
    IDCZESCI int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
    NAZWA char(30) not null CHECK ((datalength([NAZWA])>(3))),
    OPIS char(200) DEFAULT('Brak opisu'),
    CENA decimal(10,2) not null
)

CREATE TABLE MAGACZESCI
(
    IDMAGAZYNU int not null REFERENCES MAGAZYN(IDMAGAZYNU),
    IDCZESCI int not null REFERENCES CZESC(IDCZESCI),
    ILOSC float not null
)
```

I want to create a trigger that will trigger only if `ZAMOW.STATUS` changes to 'W' or 'Z' and then will subtract all values `MAGACZESCI.ILOSC = MAGACZESCI.ILOSC - ZAMOCZESCI.ILOSC` identifying id by `IDCZESCI`

For example if I have in table MAGACZESCI values (1,1,5) and (1,2,5) // 5 pieces of part number 1 and 2, in table ZAMOW(1,1,currentdate,'P'),
and in table ZAMOCZESCI (1,1,3), (1,2,2) 3 pieces of part 1 and 2 pieces of part 2

I want to trigger only if status changes from 'P' -> 'W' OR 'Z'
and then to change values in MAGACZESCI to (1,1,5-3) and (1,2,5-2) identifying by IDCZESCI

This example is for 2 rows but I want it to be more flexible, sometimes even for 100 or more rows

I came up with something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER STATUSCHANGE
ON ZAMOW
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(STATUS)
IF (ZAMOW.STATUS =  'Z' OR ZAMOW.STATUS = 'W')
DECLARE @idczesci int
DECLARE @ilosc float
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ZAMOCZESCI.IDCZESCI,ZAMOCZESCI.ILOSC FROM ZAMOCZESCI WHERE ZAMOCZESCI.IDZAMOW = ZAMOW.IDZAMOW
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @idczesci,@ilosc
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
UPDATE MAGACZESCI
SET ILOSC = ILOSC - @ilosc
WHERE IDCZESCI = @idczesci
END
GO
```

But I don't know how to tell SQL that `IF (ZAMOW.STATUS = 'Z' OR ZAMOW.STATUS = 'W')` id for rows that are updated, it tells me couldn't bound because of multipart identifier.

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far? If not, have you had a look at the [documentation on triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), than explains how they work, and how to access the data that was both `inserted` and `deleted`?

Comment: *"i am working on is not in deleted or inserted"* yes it is, when you `UPDATE` a table the old data is "deleted" and the new data is "inserted"; thus, unsurprisingly, you find that information is the `deleted` and `inserted` pseudo tables.

Comment: but how can i specify trigger that will work only if status changes to certain letter like 'W' or 'Z' ? i was told on lessons that it can be only after update, delete or insert

Comment: You'll need a `WHERE`. A `TRIGGER` will always happen on a DML statement that it is define on; it's not conditional.

Comment: also we can simplify that only 1 row can be updated in table zamow at once

Comment: *"also we can simplify that only 1 row can be updated in table zamow at once"* **never** *assume* that a DML statement can only ever effect one row in a `TRIGGER`. Also, a `CURSOR` is a really bad idea too. A `TRIGGER` needs to be a minimal as possible and `CURSOR` is the opposite of that; using one will be awful for performance.

Comment: Dude. Lock your phone when it's in your pocket

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

This is incomplete as in your attempt you reference the columns that don't exist in the table `ZAMOW` yet that is what the trigger is on. I suspect that is because we have incomplete DDL as you have keys on tables like `MAGAZYN` that don't exist in the DDL you provide.

Anyway, this should be enough to get you where you need to be, however, I can't test it, as the columns `ILOSC` and `idczesci` don't exist in your sample DDL:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_StatusChange ON dbo.ZAMOW
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE ([Status]) BEGIN

        UPDATE M
        SET ILOSC = ILOSC - i.ILOSC --This column doesn't exist in your table, so where is it coming from?
        FROM dbo.MAGACZESCI M
             JOIN inserted i ON M.IDCZESCI = i.idczesci --This column doesn't exist in your table, so where is it coming from?
             JOIN deleted d ON i.IDZAMOW = d.IDZAMOW --This column doesn't exist in your table, so where is it coming from?
        WHERE d.[STATUS] = 'P'
          AND i.[status] != 'P';
    END;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

..just a try...maybe you get something out of it..

```
drop table if exists ZAMOCZESCI_test
go
drop table if exists MAGACZESCI_test
go
drop table if exists ZAMOW_test
go
drop table if exists CZESC_test
go


CREATE TABLE ZAMOW_test
(
    IDZAMOW int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
    IDKLIENTA int not null, -- REFERENCES KLIENT(IDKLIENTA),
    DATA DATE not null DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    STATUS char(1) CHECK(STATUS = 'P' OR STATUS = 'W' OR STATUS = 'Z' OR STATUS = 'A' )DEFAULT('P')
)
go

insert into ZAMOW_test(IDKLIENTA)
values(510), (520),(530);
go


CREATE TABLE CZESC_test
(
    IDCZESCI int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
    NAZWA char(30) not null CHECK ((datalength([NAZWA])>(3))),
    OPIS char(200) DEFAULT('Brak opisu'),
    CENA decimal(10,2) not null
)
go
insert into CZESC_test(NAZWA, CENA)
values('A123', 4), ('B567', 3), ('C009', 7),
--
('X001', 150), ('X002', 500), ('X003', 700)
;
go


CREATE TABLE ZAMOCZESCI_test
(
    IDZAMOW int not null REFERENCES ZAMOW_test(IDZAMOW),
    IDCZESCI int not null REFERENCES CZESC_test(IDCZESCI),
    ILOSC float not null
)
go

insert into ZAMOCZESCI_test(IDZAMOW, IDCZESCI, ILOSC)
values(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 9),
--2nd&3rd clients
(2, 4, 60), (2, 5, 100), (2, 6, 300),
            (3, 5, 150), (3, 6, 120);
go


CREATE TABLE MAGACZESCI_test
(
    IDMAGAZYNU int not null,-- REFERENCES MAGAZYN(IDMAGAZYNU),
    IDCZESCI int not null REFERENCES CZESC_test(IDCZESCI),
    ILOSC float not null
)
go

insert into MAGACZESCI_test(IDMAGAZYNU, IDCZESCI, ILOSC)
values (1001, 1, 5), (1002, 2, 5), (1003, 3, 20),
--
(1004, 4, 200), (1005, 5, 1000), (1006, 6, 2000);
--client 2, assigned 60units of prod4, after trigger: prod4 = 200-60=140 
--clients 2&3, assigned 100+150 units of prod5, after trigger: prod5 = 1000 - (100+150)  = 750
-- prod6, after trigger: prod6 = 2000 - (300+120) = 1580
go

--based on this
/*
select *
from ZAMOW_test as zam --<--(is replaced by deleted&inserted)
join ZAMOCZESCI_test as zamcze on zam.IDZAMOW = zamcze.IDZAMOW --but this needs to get grouped by IDCZESCI, if multiple "orders" change status in a single update
join MAGACZESCI_test as mag on zamcze.IDCZESCI = mag.IDCZESCI
*/

go
create trigger trgUpdateZAMOW_test on ZAMOW_test for /*after*/ update
as
begin
    --set nocount on
    --set rowcount 0
    
    --if status did not change from p->w or z, do nothing, return/exit
    if not exists
    (
        select *
        from deleted as d
        join inserted as i on d.IDZAMOW = i.IDZAMOW
        where d.STATUS = 'P' 
        and i.STATUS in ('W', 'Z')
    )
    begin
        return;
    end

    --get the "orders" which changed from p->w||z, aggregate their products and subtract the product sums from "inventory"?
    
    update mag
    set ILOSC = mag.ILOSC - updcze.sumILOSC  --what happens if mag.ILOSC - updcze.sumILOSC < 0 ??
    --output deleted.*, inserted.*  
    from 
    (
        select zamcze.IDCZESCI, isnull(sum(zamcze.ILOSC), 0) as sumILOSC
        from deleted as d
        join inserted as i on d.IDZAMOW = i.IDZAMOW
        join ZAMOCZESCI_test as zamcze on d.IDZAMOW = zamcze.IDZAMOW
        where d.STATUS = 'P' 
        and i.STATUS in ('W', 'Z')
        group by zamcze.IDCZESCI
        having isnull(sum(zamcze.ILOSC), 0) <> 0
    ) as updcze
    join MAGACZESCI_test as mag on updcze.IDCZESCI = mag.IDCZESCI;

end
go

update ZAMOW_test
set STATUS = 'A' --trigger fires and returns/exits, x->A
go

update ZAMOW_test
set STATUS = 'W' --trigger fires and returns/exits,  status:from A->W
go

update ZAMOW_test
set STATUS = 'P' --trigger fires, exits, status:from W->P
go


select 'before', *
from MAGACZESCI_test

update ZAMOW_test
set STATUS = 'W' --trigger fires , and updates mag, status: from P->W

select 'after', *
from MAGACZESCI_test;
```

Comment: Wow, I just reviewed your code, i havent considered this approach to this problem, i wanted to iterate on this table, because im not really sql programmer and this is only for school project. But thank for showing me this, i will try later in my programming to think like u did there. Also i didnt know i can filter data by tables inserted and deleted but now i know